# VBA Excel dataform not displaying the right input and fields

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have the following VBA code, which should show a dataform from another hidden sheet.

```
Sub CoverageBssEntry()

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Sheets("myhiddensheet").Select
   Range("myTable[#All]").Select
   ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm

End Sub
```

When I run this, the data form does not containt the labels and inputboxes of this table.

Any help is really appreciated, because it is driving me nuts! My only other option is to spend time to build custom made user forms, while this would do perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to use:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(x,y).Select
```

prior calling the .ShowDataForm, works like a jiffy!

Comment: Doesn't work in Excel 2019. But this one did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650520/3286607

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select a hidden sheet.  And anyway the `.Select` statements are not necessary

Try

```
Sheets("myhiddensheet").ShowDataForm
```

Comment: But I have more tables inside that sheet? How would that make sense if I don't select the table? Also - is there a reference/pointer in the excel documentation that mentions the limitations of showdataform.

Comment: This answer is bogus - you can select a hidden sheet, and you DO need a .Select statement.

Comment: Worksheet("Nmae").Select makes the sheet "Name" active but if "Name" is hidden .Select errors.  And .ShowDataForm work on the specified worksheet object not the selection

Answer (score 1):

I think there are genuine constraints with the ShowDataForm command. It works fine if invoked outside of VBA while in a specific range. But once coded into VBA, it will only return the form for the first table in the referenced worksheet, even if a macro was recorded to perform that action.
I cannot tell why. Maybe because the showdataform event is tied to the worksheet and not to the table or list selected when it is called. Sorry guys. Maybe microsoft will improve this in the future.