# Open an Excel Form to read a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am not being able to open a the Form to read a table (and edit it) on a specific sheet called "Tasks" with:

```
Sub Button6_Click()

   ' Activate the sheet that contains your database.
         Worksheets("Tasks").Activate

         ' Show the data form for the selected range.
         ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
End Sub
```

That occurs because Excel doesn't know what to read? There is just one table on sheet "Tasks".

Comment: See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/110462), can it find the data?

Comment: I didnt manage following that procedures. I gave a name to the table, but the instructions are pointing to different direction: "o define your data with the defined name "database" . In INSERT tab i dont have such options as descrived in the workaround. I am a bit lost here..

Comment: what error do you get when you debug it?

Comment: Where does your table start?

Comment: my table starts in cell b2 of sheet 2 (name Tasks). Actually from b2 to j2 are the headers, content is below that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your table range and give it the name "Database", before showing the form, as follows:

```
Worksheets("Tasks").Activate
Range("B2:J30").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=ActiveSheet.Name & "!Database",RefersToR1C1:=Selection
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
```